# Intersection of two subspaces of a Hilbert space

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, group-algebras

Background:
   Let $D$ be a Klein Four group and consider free product $Z/2Z\star D=<a,b,c,d|a^{2}=b^{2}=c^{2}=d^{2}=bcd=1>$. Now we consider group algebra generated by  $Z/2Z\star D$ with inner product $<f,g>=tr(g^{*}f)$. After taking completion, we have a Hilbert space.

Question:
    Now Let $u=\frac{b+c+d-1}{2}$, consider two closed subspaces of the above Hilbert space $L=\overline{<(au)^{k}|k\in N>}$ and $\overline{uL}$. Can we prove that these two subspaces has nontrivial intersection?

I believe there is nontrivial intersection. My idea is to construct a nontrivial intersection directly. Say there exists $f_{i}\in \mathbb{C}$ and $g_{i} \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{i}f_{i}(au)^i=\sum_{i}g_{i}u(au)^{i}$. But I don't know how to deal with this equality.

Comment: 1. If $g=\sum \alpha_i g_i$, then $g^*=\sum \bar\alpha_i g_i^{-1}$?


2. Is it true that $\overline{uL}=u\bar L$ ?

3. Why do you think these two subspaces have a non-trivial intersection?

Comment: @MarkSapir    Yes,you are right. I think they have nontrivial intersection, because these two subspaces are not orthogonal to each other.  This is just guess. It might be true that their intersection is trivial.

Comment: I do not think so. If $p=\sum \alpha_ig_i$ is in the group algebra, then the norm of $p$ is $||p||=\sqrt{\sum |\alpha_i|^2}$. So you need to have two sequences of elements of the group algebra: $p_j=\sum \alpha_{i,j} (au)^i $ and $q_j=u\sum \beta_{i,j}(au)^i$ such that the norms of $p_j, q_j$ do not converge to 0, but the norm of $p_j-q_j$ converges to 0. This, I think, means that $p_j$ and $q_j$, viewed as elements of the group algebra, must have many common summands (i.e., all summands with "large" coefficients must disappear in $p_j-q_j$).  I think this is unlikely.